# Mystery: All postgres databases disapeared

Tags: postgresql, macos, postgres.app

I'm developing a Rails application with a postgresql database.

- MacOS 10.15.3
- ruby 2.6.3p62
- postgres 12.3

I took a break and when I came back my laptop was slow to wake up. After pressing the on/off fingerprint button a few times, it eventually went into the startup sequence. This was odd because I did not recall shutting it off.

After starting, everything seemed normal. I opened some applications and resumed my work. But, when I tried to run a database migration, I got errors about not being able to connect to the server.

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby26, which recognizes
warning: 2.6.5-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.6.3.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/Users/emerson/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/emerson/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to start it with homebrew but no luck. I eventually read another question that suggested installing the [Postgres app](https://postgresapp.com/) and using this to force it to restart. At first the app said "Empty data directory". I clicked "Initialize" and it worked. And I no longer get the bad connection error. **But ALL my previous postgres databases are gone.**

I'm puzzled. How could this have happened? And with almost no interaction from me whatsoever! Did Postgres.app wipe all my previous data with one click?

Comment: You should have a look at your postgres log file. Installing additional software when your database most likely crashed should be avoided at all cost. Instead the current situation should be first analyzed. I wouldn't be surprised if this installed a new version of postgres and most likely also removed the old postgres log file and your previous databases.

Comment: "I tried to start it with homebrew but no luck"  I find that reading the error messages and log files improves my luck.